# Flex Mobile TabbedView Applicatin Hide tabbar in states

Tags: hide, tabbar, states

I am building a tabbed view mobile application in Flash Builder 4.6 and want to have a login screen into it.

I have 5 tabs, and on the first view page I have 2 states.

1 state for a login, and another state for the actual tab itself.   I could make these but would like to hide the tabbar when it is in the login state.

I have found some things where you can turn it off by clicking on buttons, but how about just turning it of in the first view page (login state).

I tried this :

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        textAlign="center" title="Daily Settings"
    creationComplete="view2_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    ...
protected function view2_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                this.tabBarVisible = false;
            }
```

but strangely it will only dissapear on certain moments and not the whole time...

Comment: I could do it with the usage of preinitialize!  The next thing is that I want to put an if function in it.  if (currentState == "Login") {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    this.tabBarVisible = false;
   }
   else {
   this.tabBarVisible = true; 
   }

But this isn't working lol...

Answer (score 1):

Got it on another thread (sorry for double posting... guess programming drives me nuts)
[Hide tabbar in login state flex builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887969/hide-tabbar-in-login-state-flex-builder)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        currentState="login" tabBarVisible="{currentState!='login'}">
    <s:actionContent>
        <s:Button includeIn="login" label="login" click="currentState='planner'"/>
    </s:actionContent>
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="login"/>
        <s:State name="planner"/>
    </s:states>
</s:View>
```